# Android Emulator disconnects and restarts repeatedly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Recently I can't debug the Android app using the emulator because it disconnects and reconnects frequently. I can run the app in the emulator normally, but I cannot debug it. I click attach debugger to the Android process, but after a few seconds, I've lost the connection again. This problem does not occur if I run it on real devices.

Environment:

- macOS 10.15.7
- Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3 Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292
- Android Emulator v30.8.4
- HAXM installer 7.6.5

[image: Link issues]

Comment: Try to Cold Boot the device if the error still exists Wipe Data and start it again

Comment: i've uninstall emulator, delete all emulator and create new one, but it not working

Comment: Uninstall HAXM and Install it again

Comment: After uninstall, i can't install anymore. Maybe Intel HAXM unsupported in new macOS version.  Last month, the emulator work as normal, but now it doesn't.  i feel a little curious

Comment: Facing same issue @KeitaJunichiro, did you find any solution?

Comment: now, i only test in real devices

Comment: Just facing the same error here. Using real devices only is not really an option if you want to test backward compatibility.